# std::bitset redeclaration

Tags: c++, copy, instantiation, bitset

I would like to substract an integer from a number that my bitset represents. However, I don't know how to either a) copy a bitset to another bitset, or, b) re-instantiate a bitset:

```
bitset<7> bits(5);
int newresult=bits.to_ulong();
newresult=newresult-1;
bits=bitset<7> tempbits(newresult); // of course doesn't work
```

It is important that my end result is in *bits* bitset. How to do it properly?

Comment: `bits = bitset<7>(newresult);`

Comment: That looks like an answer, @ildjarn.

Comment: @Robᵩ: we call those freebies.

Comment: Yeah, I was just going to type that up  :( :(  http://ideone.com/whK8kw

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it, ildjarn?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
bits = bitset<7>(newresult);
```

Comment: I don't think this would be a big rep winner anyway, but thanks. :-]

Comment: Thank you, you've decided fair.

Comment: @PrimožKralj - I did this so that you could accept an answer. Don't forget to accept!